# How to check if repeating alarm is active in android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I saw a lot of questions and answers about it. I found that I can cancel the alarms using

```
.cancel( PendingIntent )
```

The problem is when I check if the alarm is set. To check it I use:

```
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(BackgroundService.this, pendingIntentRequestCode, intent, pendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

But I always get `true` as result.
The only way that I get `false` is when I cancel the `pendingIntent`.

Why is that? and How can I check only for alarm manager and not for pending intent?

EDIT: I did a little check and found that .cancel is working. But how can I check if the alarm is active or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't :-(

One of the things that is really lacking in Android is the ability to query the `AlarmManager` and get information about registered alarms.

Comment: really?! :|||||